# using a single WSocketNotifier for all WApplications in an WT app

Tags: c++, wt

I'm trying to build an application with WT which on one end must communicate with some other software through a socket, and on the other end notify every opened session (the WApplications).

The thing is, I can make it work, using a WSocketNotifier to be notified of new events on the socked BUT the WSocketNotifier is linked to a particular session.
In its constructor it does :

```
sessionId_(WApplication::instance()->sessionId()),
```

And that's a problem because I have only one socket, not one for each session.
So I feel the WSocketNotifier should be attached to some more general entity, not linked to a particular session. Is there a way to do that?

The only solution I see for now but it's not very elegant is to have a static WSocketNotifier and replace it when sessions die ...

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing of WT, but can you create a "dummy" session just for the purposes of handling the socket notifications, and forward to the real sessions from tehre? Or roll your own notifier that sessions can subscribe to?

Answer (score 0):

in your main(), create a thread that processes the data from your socket. With select, blocking read, ... Then use WServer::post() to notify your sessions that data arrived on your socket.